# Create an app using electron angular and firestore not working

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, electron

I'm trying to make an app with many angular routers, and firestore as database. All the youtube video I have seen were not really helpful for my problem, the documentations also. When `ng build`, my dist folder has structure like this, not really look like from tutorials:

[image]

My main.js:

[image]

Am I doing the right way, or is there anything that I need to know. I'd love to hear more about this.